# Probability of Inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose $X,Y$ are random variables with distinct distributions. I want to compute $P(X>Y)$. Suppose $Y=0,1,$ or $2$. If I know the values of $P(X>a)$ for $a=0,1,2$, can this be used to find $P(X>Y)$?

My ideas didn't work since $P(X>Y)$ is not the same as $P(X>0 \,\,\text{or}\,\,X>1\,\,\text{or}\,\,X>2)$ or $P(Y>0 \,\,\text{and}\,\,Y>1\,\,\text{and}\,\,Y>2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, whatever values $X$ can take, it could be worthwile to try the ``Law of total probability'':

$$\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\sum_{k=0}^2\mathbb{P}(X>Y|Y=k)\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=\sum_{k=0}^2\mathbb{P}(X>k)\mathbb{P}(Y=k).$$

So, yes, the values $\mathbb{P}(X>k)$ do help.

Edit: What I wrote above is not correct, I apologize. It is true that
$$\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\sum_{k=0}^2\mathbb{P}(X>Y|Y=k)\mathbb{P}(Y=k),$$

but the last step is generally only correct if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Are you sure that $P(X>k\mid Y=k)=P(X>k)$?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, that was too naive.

Comment: Won't $X,Y$ be independent since they have distinct distributions?

Comment: No, not necessarily. As a simplistic example, let $X=Y+10$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are highly dependent, but have completely different supports.

Answer (score 1):

Such a problem cannot be solved without learning the joint distribution of the two random variables in question. That is, knowing only the values of the random variables $P(X>Y)$ cannot be calculated, not even if we know the $P(X=i)$, $P(Y=j)$ probabilities.

Let's define the joint distribution as a matrix:

$$\begin{matrix}
&X&0&1&2\\
Y&&\\
0&&p_{0,0}&p_{0,1}&p_{0,2}\\
1&&p_{1,0}&p_{1,1}&p_{1,2}\\
2&&p_{2,0}&p_{2,1}&p_{2,2}.\\
\end{matrix}$$

Here $$p_{i,j}=P(Y=i\cap X=j).$$

Now,

$$P(X>Y)=p_{0,1}+p_{0,2}+p_{1,2}.$$

**EDITED**

Distinct distributions.

The marginals can be calculated the following way:

$$
\begin{matrix}p_0=P(Y=0)=p_{0,0}+p_{0,1}+p_{0,2}\\
p_1=P(Y=1)=p_{1,0}+p_{1,1}+p_{1,2}\\
p_2=P(Y=2)=p_{2,0}+p_{2,1}+p_{2,2}
\end{matrix}$$

and

$$\begin{matrix}
q_0=P(X=0)=p_{0,0}+p_{1,0}+p_{2,0}\\
q_1=P(X=1)=p_{0,1}+p_{1,1}+p_{2,1}\\
q_2=P(X=2)=p_{0,2}+p_{1,2}+p_{2,2}.
\end{matrix}$$

The question becomes a problem in linear a algebra:

Can we compute $$P(X>Y)=p_{0,1}+p_{0,2}+p_{1,2}.$$ if $p_0\not = q_0$, $p_1\not = q_1$, $p_2\not = q_2$, $\sum p_i=\sum q_i=1$, and $\sum\sum p_{i,j}=1.$

????

Comment: Will that be the joint distribution if $X$ can take values other than 0,1,2?

Comment: @IcedPalmer: I don't quite understand... The joint distribution of two discrete random variables is always a matrix possibly indexed by pairs of values taken by those random variables. We have here $\{0,1,2\}\times\{0,1,2\}.$ But we could have anything else.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Is it feasible to compute the $p_{i,j}$ if $X,Y$ have distinct distributions?

Comment: I will edit my answer for you.

Comment: I've edited my ans.